# Search time complexity of this sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, big-o, time-complexity

This table provides information about real estates. The column “Type” contains either the value “Apartment”, “House”, “Townhouse” or “Villa”. The number of entries for each type is roughly 25% of the total number of entries in the table.

Table Name  Column Name Data Type
RealEstate  ID  DEC(10)
    Type    VARCHAR(40)
    Price   DEC(10,2)
    Size    DEC(4)
A typical query asks for all real estates of a given type:
select ID 
from   RealEstate
where  Type = ′House’
Two indexes were defined for this table. The first index was defined for the column ′ID′ and the second index was defined for the column ′Type′. what will be the time complexity of this query relative to the number of entries n and the size of the result set m??

the time complexity will be O (log(n)+m) or O(n)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very roughly speaking and in a way a speculation:

The complexity should be O(m) because due to the indexes present,
the DB engine can find/locate the records matching `Type = 'House'`
in constant time. So all that is taking time here is to process the
matching records whose count is m (e.g. to read them and to return
them to the caller). So the complexity is O(m) because the processing
is proportional to the count of the records returned.

But when viewed at a lower level, I guess it all depends on many other things too:
if your index is well-maintained (not fragmented), if the records are well-situated
on the disk (e.g. sequentially), etc, etc. So it is hard to give a direct/simple
big O formula.

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity will probably be O(n).

This question is another way of asking "will this query use an index scan or a full table scan?"  In general, index range scans work better when looking up a small percent of the rows.  And, in general, full table scans work better when looking up a large percent of the rows.

There's no one "magic number".  But in my experience, with a table of any significant size, 25% is definitely in the full table scan region.

This decision depends on a lot of factors: caching, multi-block read count, physical storage, statistics (object and system), clustering factor (how well are rows stored on disk - since Oracle retrieves data one block at a time a query may need to read 100% of the blocks to read 1% of the data), etc.

**Code sample**

Here's a simple example demonstration a full table scan.  Note that I'm using 100000 rows.  If the question is about a table with only a handful of rows than the time complexity is irrelevant as constant overhead will be more significant than the algorithms.

```
create table RealEstate
(
    ID       DEC(10),
    Type     VARCHAR(40),
    Price    DEC(10,2),
    the_Size DEC(4)
);
create index RealEstate_idx on RealEstate(type);

insert into RealEstate
select level, decode(mod(level, 4), 0, 'Apartment', 1, 'House', 2, 'Townhouse', 3, 'Villa') , 100, 100
from dual connect by level <= 100000;
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'realestate');
end;
/
```

**Execution plan**

Note the `TABLE ACCESS FULL`.

```
explain plan for select * from RealEstate where type = 'House';
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);


Plan hash value: 4238863598

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |            | 25000 |   463K|   103   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| REALESTATE | 25000 |   463K|   103   (1)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("TYPE"='House')
```